# Turn window scroll back on after turning it off for a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script using the window scroll to add effects to my header container.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $('#main-page').addClass('appear');
        $('#logo1').fadeOut(0);
        $('#logo2').show(0);
    }
    else  {
        $('#logo2').hide(0);
        $('#logo1').fadeIn(0);
        $('#main-page').removeClass('appear');

    }


    });
```

I have this function on the page that I use to trigger my chart function when the user scrolls on the div

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#token-stats').offset().top,
       hH = $('#token-stats').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log((hT-wH) , wS);
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){

    drawDoughnutChart();
     $(window).off('scroll')
   }

});
```

am I suppose to be trying to turn it back on in the first function, or do I add something to the chart function where I turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to use [jQuery `namespaces`](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) so you will `off` only the chart's scroll but not the logo's scroll.

So in the second script you need to do something like this:

```js
$(window).on('scroll.chart', function() {
  var hT = $('#token-stats').offset().top,
    hH = $('#token-stats').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log((hT - wH), wS);
  if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {

    drawDoughnutChart();
    $(window).off('scroll.chart')
  }
});
```

While `$(window).off('scroll.chart')` will `off` only this handler.

[For more info](https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/)

Comment: worked perfectly, you taught me something today. Happy new year!

Comment: My pleasure :) please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/303669) the answer so it will help to other people.